# Scala + How to do placeholder replacement in Spark Dataframe Column from file?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

### MyPlaceHolder.json

```
[[" PHPHONENUMBER ", "(^|\\W)(\\+\\d{1,}\\s*\\(?\\d{1,}\\)?[\\s|\\-|\\d{1,}]{1,})($|\\W)"],    
  [" PHPHONENUMBER ", "(^|\\W)(\\(0[\\d\\s]{1,}\\)[\\s|\\-|\\d{1,}]{1,})($|\\W)"],[" PHPHONENUMBER ", "(^|\\W)(\\+\\d{1,}\\s*\\(?\\d{1,}\\)?[\\s|\\-|\\d{1,}]{1,})($|\\W)"],    
  [" PHPHONENUMBER ", "(^|\\W)(\\(0[\\d\\s]{1,}\\)[\\s|\\-|\\d{1,}]{1,})($|\\W)"],[" PHPHONENUMBER ", "(^|\\W)(\\+\\d{1,}\\s*\\(?\\d{1,}\\)?[\\s|\\-|\\d{1,}]{1,})($|\\W)"],    
  [" PHPHONENUMBER ", "(^|\\W)(\\(0[\\d\\s]{1,}\\)[\\s|\\-|\\d{1,}]{1,})($|\\W)"],[" PHPHONENUMBER ", "(^|\\W)(\\+\\d{1,}\\s*\\(?\\d{1,}\\)?[\\s|\\-|\\d{1,}]{1,})($|\\W)"],    
  [" PHPHONENUMBER ", "(^|\\W)(\\(0[\\d\\s]{1,}\\)[\\s|\\-|\\d{1,}]{1,})($|\\W)"]]
```

Basically, I need to read this file and replace the pattern in DF column with the placeholder.

For Ex : any Pattern like this `"(^|\\W)(\\+\\d{1,}\\s*\\(?\\d{1,}\\)?[\\s|\\-|\\d{1,}]{1,})($|\\W)" shold get replace with " PHPHONENUMBER "`

I python I have done something like this as below.

```
replacement_patterns = get_config_object__(os.getcwd() + REPLACEMENT_PATTERN_FILE_PATH)


def placeholder_replacement(text, replacement_patterns):
    """
     This function replace the place holder with reference to replacement_patterns.

     Parameters
     ----------
     text : String
         Input string to the function.

     replacement_patterns : json
         json object of placeholder replacement_patterns pattern.

     Returns
     -------
     text : String
         Output string with replacement of placeholder.
     """

    for replacement, pattern in replacement_patterns:
        text = re.compile(pattern, re.IGNORECASE | re.UNICODE).sub(replacement, text)
    return text

def get_config_object__(config_file_path):
    """
     This function mainly load the configuration object in json form.

     Parameters
     ----------
     config_file_path : str
         Configuration path.

     Returns
     -------
     config_object : JSON object
         Configuration object.
     """

    config_file = open(config_file_path)
    config_object = json.load(config_file)
    config_file.close()
    return config_object
```

How can I replace this kind of file replacement in data frame column?

```
Note:: I can not change file, its cross used a placeholder.json.(I know it's not json but can't help it)

Its inside resource folder.
```

Here is the thing which I am trying, however its just experiment. Please feel free to suggest something out of the box.
nothing working out, I have tried different things but as I m new to the language I need help.

```
    val inputPath = getClass.getResource("/input_data/placeholder_replacement.txt").getPath

    val inputDF = spark.read.option("delimiter", "|").option("header", true).option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace", true).option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace", true).csv(inputPath)


    val replacement_pattern = getClass.getResource("/unitmetrics-replacement-patterns.json").getPath

    val replacement_pattern_DF = (spark.read.text(replacement_pattern))


    val myval = replacement_pattern_DF.rdd.map(row => row.getString(0).split("],").toList).collect()


    val removeNonGermanLetterFunction = udf((col: String) => {



      myval.foreach { x =>

        x.foreach { x =>

          var key = x.split("\",")(0).replaceAll("[^0-9a-zA-ZäöüßÄÖÜẞ _]", "")
          var value = x.split("\",")(1).replaceAll("\"", "")

          val regex = value.r

          regex.replaceAllIn(col, key)


        }
      }
    }
    )


    val input = inputDF.withColumn("new", removeNonGermanLetterFunction(col("duplicate_word_col")))

    input.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Spark DataFrame (also called Spark SQL) [API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html) whenever possible, instead of the lower level RDD API that you showed (`rdd.map()`, `rdd.foreach()`...).

This generally means loading your data inside a DataFrame `df` and then using `df.withColumn()` to create new columns with a transformation applied to previous columns. RDDs are still used below at the end, but of lot of things are optimized for you by using the high level DataFrame API.

Here's a little Scala application showing how to apply pattern replacements to a DataFrame using Spark SQL function `regexp_replace`.

```scala
import org.apache.log4j.{Logger, Level}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column

object Main {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    // Set logging level to avoid Spark log spam
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
    Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

    // Build Spark SQL session (mine is version 2.3.2)
    val spark = SparkSession.builder
      .appName("scalaTest1")
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()

    // Import required to use Spark SQL methods like toDF() and calling columns with '
    import spark.implicits._

    // Create some basic DataFrame
    val df1 = List(
      (1, "I got pattern1 and pattern2."),
      (2, "I don't have any."),
      (3, "Oh, that pattern1 I have too.")
    ).toDF("id", "sentence")

    df1.show(false)
    //+---+-----------------------------+
    //|id |sentence                     |
    //+---+-----------------------------+
    //|1  |I got pattern1 and pattern2. |
    //|2  |I don't have any.            |
    //|3  |Oh, that pattern1 I have too.|
    //+---+-----------------------------+

    // Create replacements map
    val replacements = Map(
      "pattern1" -> "replacement1",
      "pattern2" -> "replacement2",
      "I " -> "you "
    )

    // Import required to use functions on DataFrame columns such as regexp_replace()
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

    // Create a new column with one of the replacements applied to "sentence" column
    val df2 = df1.withColumn(
      "new",
      regexp_replace('sentence, "pattern1", replacements("pattern1"))
    )

    df2.show(false)
    //+---+-----------------------------+---------------------------------+
    //|id |sentence                     |new                              |
    //+---+-----------------------------+---------------------------------+
    //|1  |I got pattern1 and pattern2. |I got replacement1 and pattern2. |
    //|2  |I don't have any.            |I don't have any.                |
    //|3  |Oh, that pattern1 I have too.|Oh, that replacement1 I have too.|
    //+---+-----------------------------+---------------------------------+

    // With the first two replacements applied to "sentence" column by nesting one inside the other
    val df3 = df1.withColumn(
      "new",
      regexp_replace(
        regexp_replace('sentence, "pattern2", replacements("pattern2")),
        "pattern1",
        replacements("pattern1")
      )
    )

    df3.show(false)
    //+---+-----------------------------+------------------------------------+
    //|id |sentence                     |new                                 |
    //+---+-----------------------------+------------------------------------+
    //|1  |I got pattern1 and pattern2. |I got replacement1 and replacement2.|
    //|2  |I don't have any.            |I don't have any.                   |
    //|3  |Oh, that pattern1 I have too.|Oh, that replacement1 I have too.   |
    //+---+-----------------------------+------------------------------------+

    // Same, but applying all replacements recursively with "foldLeft" instead of nesting every replacement
    val df4 = df1.withColumn(
      "new",
      replacements.foldLeft(df1("sentence")) {
        case (c: Column, (pattern: String, replacement: String)) => regexp_replace(c, pattern, replacement)
      }
    )
    df4.show(false)
    //+---+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------+
    //|id |sentence                     |new                                   |
    //+---+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------+
    //|1  |I got pattern1 and pattern2. |you got replacement1 and replacement2.|
    //|2  |I don't have any.            |you don't have any.                   |
    //|3  |Oh, that pattern1 I have too.|Oh, that replacement1 you have too.   |
    //+---+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------+

    // Select the columns you want to keep and rename if necessary
    val df5 = df4.select('id, 'new).withColumnRenamed("new", "sentence")
    df5.show(false)
    //+---+--------------------------------------+
    //|id |sentence                              |
    //+---+--------------------------------------+
    //|1  |you got replacement1 and replacement2.|
    //|2  |you don't have any.                   |
    //|3  |Oh, that replacement1 you have too.   |
    //+---+--------------------------------------+

  }

}
```

There are various libraries to read from JSON in Scala, here I'm going to use a [Spark SQL method](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-json.html) `spark.read.json(path)` to not add another dependency, even though it might be considered overkill to use Spark to read such a small file.

Note that the function I use expects a specific file format of one valid JSON object per line, and you should be able to map the fields of the JSON to columns of dataframes.

This is the content of the file `replacements.json` I've created:

```
{"pattern":"pattern1" , "replacement": "replacement1"}
{"pattern":"pattern2" , "replacement": "replacement2"}
{"pattern":"I " , "replacement": "you "}
```

And here's the little app rewritten to read replacements from this file, put them into a map, and then apply them to the data with the foldLeft method I showed at the end of the previous one.

```scala
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Column, SparkSession}

object Main2 {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    // Set logging level to avoid Spark log spam
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
    Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

    // Build Spark SQL session (mine is version 2.3.2)
    val spark = SparkSession.builder
      .appName("scalaTest1")
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()

    // Import required to use Spark SQL methods like toDF() and calling columns with '
    import spark.implicits._
    // Import required to use functions on DataFrame columns such as regexp_replace()
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._


    // Create some basic DataFrame
    val df1 = List(
      (1, "I got pattern1 and pattern2."),
      (2, "I don't have any."),
      (3, "Oh, that pattern1 I have too.")
    ).toDF("id", "sentence")
    df1.show(false)
    //+---+-----------------------------+
    //|id |sentence                     |
    //+---+-----------------------------+
    //|1  |I got pattern1 and pattern2. |
    //|2  |I don't have any.            |
    //|3  |Oh, that pattern1 I have too.|
    //+---+-----------------------------+

    // Read replacements json file into a DataFrame
    val replacements_path = "/path/to/your/replacements.json"
    val replacements_df = spark.read.json(replacements_path)
    replacements_df.show(false)
    //+--------+------------+
    //|pattern |replacement |
    //+--------+------------+
    //|pattern1|replacement1|
    //|pattern2|replacement2|
    //|I       |you         |
    //+--------+------------+

    // Turn DataFrame into a Map for ease of use in next step
    val replacements_map = replacements_df
      .collect() // Brings all the df data from all Spark executors to the Spark driver, use only if df is small!
      .map(row => (row.getAs[String]("pattern"), row.getAs[String]("replacement")))
      .toMap
    print(replacements_map)
    // Map(pattern1 -> replacement1, pattern2 -> replacement2, I  -> you )

    // Apply replacements recursively with "foldLeft"
    val df2 = df1.withColumn(
      "new",
      replacements_map.foldLeft(df1("sentence")) {
        case (c: Column, (pattern: String, replacement: String)) => regexp_replace(c, pattern, replacement)
      }
    )
    df2.show(false)
    //+---+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------+
    //|id |sentence                     |new                                   |
    //+---+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------+
    //|1  |I got pattern1 and pattern2. |you got replacement1 and replacement2.|
    //|2  |I don't have any.            |you don't have any.                   |
    //|3  |Oh, that pattern1 I have too.|Oh, that replacement1 you have too.   |
    //+---+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------+

    // Select the columns you want to keep and rename if necessary
    val df3 = df2.select('id, 'new).withColumnRenamed("new", "sentence")
    df3.show(false)
    //+---+--------------------------------------+
    //|id |sentence                              |
    //+---+--------------------------------------+
    //|1  |you got replacement1 and replacement2.|
    //|2  |you don't have any.                   |
    //|3  |Oh, that replacement1 you have too.   |
    //+---+--------------------------------------+

  }

}
```

In your final app, remove the `df.show()` and `print()`.
Spark "transformations" are "lazy". It means Spark will just stack what you ask it to do into an execution graph (DAG) without executing. It's only when you will force him to act, for example when you use `df.show()` or `df.save()` to write data somewhere (these are called "actions"), that it will analyze the DAG, optimize it, and actually execute the transformations on the data.
That's why you should avoid using actions such as `df.show()` on intermediate transformations.

Comment: Thank you so much NicolasPA , can you please tell me how i can load my json file of patterns and replacement in  Map  (my example json file is given in question)  ``` val replacements = Map(
      "pattern1" -> "replacement1",
      "pattern2" -> "replacement2",
      "I " -> "you "
    )``` can you suggest me how i can load my json file in to Map

Comment: can you please help ?

Comment: I have updated my answer with a way to read the replacements from a JSON file.

Comment: Actually that is the catch , if you see my question you will understand it that I can not prepare json file , its cross functional used json file.so i can not change it , I have to use same file. actually its extention is just json but it is not json. and that is the reason i was trying with low level api of DF. I really appriciate that u are trying to help me but i would really get rid of this problem you give me some idea to first read this kind of format and convert it in to map. (I have given sample of  pattern file in question)Thanks lot NicolasPA

Comment: Can you please help ?